# My preloader won't disappear unless I load the page again with Ctrl + Shift + R. What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preloader

My preloader won't disappear when I refresh the page normally or go to it from the folder on my computer. It only works when I load it ignoring the cache by Ctrl + Shift + R. What could be the problem? Also, at the moment the delay code isn't working at all so whenever it kind of works, it just disappears in a split second.

There can be errors in the code - I am a real beginner :). Thanks for your help in advance!

```
$(function(){
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    if (!sessionStorage.isVisited) {
  sessionStorage.isVisited = 'true'
  $(".preloader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow")
  $(".preloader-wrapper").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow")
} else {
  $(".preloader").hide()
  $(".preloader-wrapper").hide()
}
});;
});
```

Comment: You should to know the next difference: [load and ready](https://coderwall.com/p/_jothq/jquery-when-to-use-document-ready-and-when-window-load) and [ready and `$(function()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). I think you don't need to use them both one inside the another.

Answer (score 0):

"load" event is fired when page is loaded, you may hide preloader on "load" event and show it when script started it's execution. Sorry if I understood something wrong.